# Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm working on Idle and when I ask to check the file, it says no problems. When I run it though, it crashes the app. I'm also working on a MAC, I don't know if that will influence anything. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code? I'm still fairly new, so any help is appreciated. 
Also what I am trying to do is mostly imbed a matplotlib animation into a GUI when the GUI has the entries for the animation data, and a button to call the animation is on the GUI as well. Ideally the button would be clicked and  the Animation would show up above the two entries. I have been working on this program for a while, but imbedding the animation/ getting the button to callback the graph has been the most troublesome part.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import * 
import time 
import pyaudio 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
import numpy as np 

import random 

fig = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 


def get_data(): 
    while True: 


        return x, mylist 

class App(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, root): 
        self.root = root 
        self.root.title("Testing") 
        self.setupTk() 
        self.quit_button = Button(master=self.root, text='Quit', command=self._quit) 
        self.quit_button.pack(side='right') 
        def _quit(self): 
            self.root.destroy() 

fig = plt.Figure() 

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)        # x-array 

def animate(i): 
    line.set_ydata(np.sin((x+i/10.0)))  # update the data 
    return line, 

root = tk.Tk() 
label = tk.Label(root,text="SHM Simulation").grid(column=0, row=0) 

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root) 
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=1) 
entry1= Entry(root, text='Frequency') 
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1) 

entry2= Entry(root, text='Duration') 
canvas.get_tk.widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1) 
entry2.pack() 

f=int(entry1.get()) 
t=float(entry2.get()) 

def callback(): 
    p=pyaudio.Pyaudio 
    fs=44100 
    volume=.7 
    samples=(np.sin(f*2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*t)/(fs).astype(np/float32))) 
    stream=p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, 
                  channels=1, 
                  rate=fs, 
                  output=True) 
    stream.write(volume*samples) 

b=Button(root, text='Sound', command=callback) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x)) 
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), interval=25, blit=False) 

def on_click(self): 

        if self.ani is None: 

           return self.start() 

        if self.running: 

            self.ani.event_source.stop() 
            self.btn.config(text='Un-Pause') 
        else: 

            self.ani.event_source.start() 
            self.btn.config(text='Pause') 
        self.running = not self.running 
        def start(self): 
            self.points = int(self.points_ent.get()) + 1 
            self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation( 
                self.fig, 
                self.update_graph, 
                frames=self.points, 
                interval=int(self.interval.get()), 
                repeat=False) 
            self.running = True 
            self.btn.config(text='Pause') 
            self.ani._start() 
            print('started animation') 
            def update_graph(self, i): 
                self.line.set_data(*get_data()) # update graph 

                if i >= self.points - 1: 

                    self.btn.config(text='Start') 
                    self.running = False 
                    self.ani = None 
                return self.line, 

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk() 
    app = App(root) 
    app.pack() 
    root.mainloop() 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main
```

Comment: When the code crashes, what errors do you get?

Comment: Application Specific Backtrace, Thread 0 Crashed

Comment: To be honest this code does not make much sense. Indents are wrong and functions are defined inconsistent like def start(); what functions belong to the class App? def _quit(self) is indented too far. The code contains numerous names that are not defined (x, mylist) in function get_data; setupTk; and so on; start and on_click are never called; ... main won't work, it must be main(). I suggest you tear apart this code and build it up from scratch gradually adding functionality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was interested in the pyaudio I have tried to make your code runnable with the functionality that I think you had intended. You can build from here to add a random signal to the sine wave or use different signals all together. Main changes is that all functions are now in the class App. Also to have the audio sound and plot to run at the same time I start the audio in a different thread. 
Hope this is useful for you.

```
import threading
import random
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, Button, Entry, TOP, BOTH
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pyaudio

DEFAULT_FREQUENCY = 220
DEFAULT_DURATION = 5
VOLUME = 0.3
INTERVAL = 100

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("SHM Simulation - Testing")

        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="SHM Simulation")
        label.pack()

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=root)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
        self.ax.set_xlim(-0.1, 2 * np.pi + 0.1)

        self.quit_button = Button(master=self.root, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quit_button.pack(side='right')

        self.sound_button = Button(self.root, text='Sound off', command=self.toggle_sound)
        self.sound_button.pack(side='right')

        self.plot_button = Button(self.root, text='Start')
        self.plot_button.pack(side='right')
        self.plot_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_click)

        tk.Label(self.root, text='Frequency').pack(side='left')
        self.frequency_entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.frequency_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_FREQUENCY)
        self.frequency_entry.pack(side='left')

        tk.Label(self.root, text='Duration').pack(side='left')
        self.duration_entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.duration_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_DURATION)
        self.duration_entry.pack(side='left')

        self.ani = None
        self.running = False

        self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.sound = False
        self.samples = np.array([])

    def quit(self):
        self.audio.terminate()
        self.root.quit()

    def get_data(self, frame):
        self.ydata = np.sin(self.frequency * self.xdata + frame)

    def update_frame(self, frame):
        self.get_data(frame)
        self.line.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata)

        if frame > self.duration - 1.1 * INTERVAL / 1000 :
            self.ani = None
            self.running = False
            self.plot_button.config(text='Start')

        return self.line,

    def start_animation(self):
        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = []
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, lw=3)

        self.xdata = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.01)

        duration_range = np.arange(0, self.duration, INTERVAL / 1000)
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig,
                                 self.update_frame,
                                 frames=duration_range,
                                 interval=INTERVAL,
                                 repeat=False)

        if self.sound:
            ''' start audio in a seperate thread as otherwise audio and
                plot will not be at the same time
            '''
            x = threading.Thread(target=self.play_sound)
            x.start()

    def callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        out = self.samples[:frame_count]
        self.samples = self.samples[frame_count:]
        return (out*VOLUME, pyaudio.paContinue)

    def play_sound(self):
        fs = 44100
        self.samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * self.duration) *
                        self.frequency / fs)).astype(np.float32)

        stream = self.audio.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                                 channels=1,
                                 rate=fs,
                                 output=True,
                                 stream_callback=self.callback)

        stream.start_stream()

        # pause audio when self.running is False
        while stream.is_active():
            while not self.running:
                if stream.is_active:
                    stream.stop_stream()
                else:
                    pass

            if self.running and not stream.is_active():
                stream.start_stream()
            else:
                pass

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()

    def toggle_sound(self):
        if self.sound:
            self.sound_button.configure(text='Sound Off')
        else:
            self.sound_button.configure(text='Sound On ')

        self.sound = not self.sound

    def on_click(self, event):
        if self.ani is None:
            try:
                self.ax.lines.pop(0)

            except IndexError:
                pass

            try:
                self.frequency = int(self.frequency_entry.get())
                self.duration = int(self.duration_entry.get())

            except ValueError:
                self.frequency = DEFAULT_FREQUENCY
                self.frequency_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_FREQUENCY)
                self.duration = DEFAULT_DURATION
                self.duration_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_DURATION)

            self.start_animation()
            self.running = True
            self.plot_button.config(text='Pause')
            print('animation started ...')
            return

        if self.running:
             self.ani.event_source.stop()
             self.plot_button.config(text='Run  ')

        else:
             self.ani.event_source.start()
             self.plot_button.config(text='Pause')

        self.running = not self.running


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is how I wanted it to run. So for future reference, I would put all of my functions in a separate class?

Comment: If functions are related and they need to interact with each other it is handy to put them in one class. Note the code I submitted is not particularly easy as the concept of classes is something you need to learn and it contain threading as well. Anyway if you are happy with the answer, please can you press 'answered' for me to get my kudos. Thanks!